# What is the first order logic statement of "this field is of characteristic zero"?

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, first-order-logic, quantifiers

I want to state that a field $F$ is of characteristic zero *in logical notation* to an audience without referring them to the meaning of the characteristic of a field.

My first thought was the proposition
$\forall x \in F \setminus \{-1\} : x + 1 \ne 0,$
but this holds for any field.

How can “of characteristic zero” be stated using quantifiers?

Comment: An equivalent statement is $F$ contains a subfield isomorphic to $\mathbb Q$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. In any field the equation 
$$
x + 1 = 0
$$
has the unique solution $x = -1$, independent of the characteristic.

If your audience is unfamiliar with the characteristic of a field and you need to explain it, do that with an example. In $\mathbb{Z}_5$ you have
$1 + 1 + 1 +1 + 1 = 0$. In a field with characteristic $0$ no sum of $1$s can be $0$.

Don't use logical symbols, use words.

**Edit** in response to the edited question.

If you must use a formal statement you might say

> For every positive integer $n$ the sum of $n$ $1$s is not $0$.

or

> The smallest subfield is infinite.

Comment: It's going in a list of axioms all written in the form $\forall a, b, c, \ldots \in F : P(a, b, c, \ldots)$. Would it suffice to write $\forall n \in \mathbb{N} : \sum_{i=1}^n 1 \ne 0$?

Comment: @holomenicus That should do, with the implicit assumption that $0 \not \in \mathbb{N}$. I'm not a logician - if first order logic is what you need I trust that sum as a function of $n$ can be written in first order logic.

Answer (score 3):

No.

The statement is equivalent to

> for all $x\in F$, if $x+1=0$ then $x=-1$.

This is true in every field.

To explain characteristic zero, how about just "adding $1$ and $1$ and $1$ and so on [finitely many times] will never give you zero".  Omit the "finitely many times" if you think it will confuse your audience.  And I would certainly suggest briefly giving an example of a field with non-zero characteristic, otherwise they will just say "that's obvious, what's the point?"

Comment: +1 I was just finishing the same answer when yours appeared.